# .NET Connection pool doesn't recover after short forced single user mode of target DB

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection-pooling

Our app is connecting to our DB using following connection string:

```
Data Source=<IP>;Initial Catalog=<DBName>;User ID=<Account>;Password=<Password>
```

It uses it to try to store data in a loop that can be simplyfied by following pseudocode:

```
bool stored;
do
{
    (using)(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(StaticConnectionString))
    {
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            //Create SP command and execute here
            stored = true;
        }
        catch(Exception e){/* Log and sleep few secs */}
    }

}while(!stored)
```

We experienced some issues with blocking and extremely high disk I/O due to wrongly designed index. We put DB to single user mode:

```
ALTER DATABASE <DBName> SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
```

And fixed the issue and than flipped the DB to MULTI_USER.
After that all other instances of our exe reconnected just fine to the DB - however the exe that was trying to insert quite a lot of data (previous loop was running in dozens parallel threads for different records) hasn't recovered for hour after that (than we restarted). It was continuously getting following exception during attempt to connect:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "<DBName>" requested by the login. The login failed.
Login failed for user '<Account>'.
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at <Our Call to Connection.Open>
ClientConnectionId:9dcf1a45-0f53-4a0f-be8b-63d871ca0afd
```

Where all threads were getting the problem for the same internal connection (.NET framweork connection pool ClientConnectionId guid repeats in all the stack traces from this issue). In TCPView nd process monitor I could clearly see that the app is not even trying to create new connection to the server - it simply somehow internally remembers that the connection was failed due to SINGLE_USER mode and rethrows the exception on next attempt, and pool doesn't try to clear such a connection.
I attempted to force several full GC - no change, detach attach the database - no change; forbid network acess to sql server and reenable it - no change.

Why isn't connection pool throwing away failed connections? How can we remedy this?

Comment: You can try use SqlConnection.ClearPool() method

Comment: @PrzemekG Thanks for suggestion - I'll add some code for detection of this issue and clearing of the pool.
However question remains - why is this happening in the first place - I'd expect .NET connection pool to not pool failed connections